# How to distinguish modified item in binding list?

Tags: c#, datagridview, bindinglist

I am developing a windows application using C# and .net 4.5 under visual studio 2013 IDE.

1. In my application when the user attempt to enter a new data the program creates an object of appropriate class let's call the class `DataClass` and the to be  `objectOfDataClass`.
2. The `objectOfDataClass` is added to a `BindingList<DataClass>` let it be  `bindingListOfDataClass` which is bounded to a `DataGridView` as a data viewer.
3. The user enters data in a text boxes then he/she press a button to add text boxes value as a list item to `bindingListOfDataClass` and then he/she can view all data records on the `DataGridView`.
4. Then the user has a choice to click *save button* to save the data to a file or database.

All of these functions are working very well without any problem. But I want to add another function to mark or distinguish the new data entry or the modified cells on the `datagridview` and the `bindingList` by changing the style format of that cell (i.e: changing the background color or font style ..etc) **before** the user click the *save button* so he/she is notified to confirm any changes before saving the new entries.

The **comparison** should be between the saved data (the data on the file or database) and the data shown in the `datgridveiw`.

Now I am looking for a best solution which must achieves higher performance and preserve memory. so any suggestion please?

Comment: Try searching & using Inotification property

Answer (score 0):

Exactly here you need to distinguish newly added items and already saved items
from the list So you can easily use flag for this....

When you click on Add Button you can false your flag & then true..Before items saved you can change color or something else where flag false..